# Binding to struct

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a line drawn with points. I want allow the user to edit that points. For that I've bound an `ObservableCollection<Point>` to a `DataGrid` (X, Y columns) (actually is `DataPoint` because I'm using a library, but it still a `Struct`).

The problem is that as I'm binding to a struct and struct doesn't meant to be changed I'm modifying a copy of my collection rather than the collection itself. I would like to switch to a normal class with X,Y properties exposed but I can't. 
How could I bind to a collection of struct and get that collection modified?
Thanks.

If that's not possible, how could I target the VIEW values of the DataGrid in order to running a loop to populate a new List and then replace my first ObservableCollection with items from that new List.

`myDataGrid.Items` is not what I'm looking for because this represent the original data and not the real data in the cells of my `DataGrid`.

Comment: did you consider using the Façade Pattern?  That pattern can be used to easily overcome the difficulty...

Answer (score 2):

Structs are value types. So basically if you access them you get a copy.

That means for points, you can only overwrite them by calling the constructor and assign the new values:

```
yourPoint = new Point(xNew, yNew);
```

For DataBinding, you always have to use a Property. You could define a class for this which is wrapping your struct.

I hope this already helps. Else you can also check out this [struct tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).